# Checking for class instance within another class

Tags: php, class, token

I have created a user class that has information about the user. Also, I have extended that class with another class called LoggedInUser.

The point of LoggedInUser is to be able to easily tell if the user is authenticated and logged in by simply checking for the existence of the LoggedInUser object like this:

```
class User {
 //properties
}

class LoggedInUser extends User {
 //some additional token stuff
}

$isLoggedIn = new LoggedInUser();

class Router {
 public function gotoRoute() {
  if($isLoggedIn) {
   // perform the action
  }
 }
}
```

As far as I can tell, $isLoggedIn is not accessible to the class, so should I pass it into the constructor? or is there a better way to do all of this?

Comment: by the way, you are assigning an object to $isLoggedIn, so will it not always evaluate to TRUE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you have two options.  You can pass the `LoggedInUser` into the `Router::__construct()`.  Or you can create the `LoggedInUser` in the `Router::__construct()`

1st option:

```
$LoggedInUser = new LoggedInUser();
$Router = new Router($LoggedInUser);
```

2nd option

```
$Router = new Router();

// in router class file
__construct() {
    $this->YourProperty = new LoggedInUser();
}
```

I like the 1st option.  It is called [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Comment: Thanks charles, I too am leaning toward option 1.what about a third option in which i simply store an authID in the session and check against that? is that bad practice?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call it bad practice.  Simply with a class you can do other things with it, like easily tie it to a database, include some kind of state checking method in the class to keep all of your session methods encapsulated.  With a flat out `$_SESSION['authid']` if you wind up needing to do those type of things you could easily wind up to 'spaghetti code'.  I like encapsulation whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure if this is what you are after but what about making the $isLoggedIn a private variable so that classes can check its existence?

private $isLoggedIn = new LoggedInUser();

Comment: I think you're onto something.. I'll get back to you on that

Answer (score 0):

First of all, variables are always locale to a class. You cannot assign a variable outside of a class and then call it.

In a simple script like this, that's what I would do:

```
class Router {
    public function gotoRoute() {
        $isLoggedIn = $isLoggedIn = new LoggedInUser();
        if( $isLoggedIn instanceof User ) {
        // perform the action
        }
    }
}
```